# Editing ofm format

Tags: gratis, forms

I need to edit some .ofm forms but I don't have [Nuance OmniForm](http://www.nuance.com/vista/omniform/), which is a $99 editor.

Is there a freeware version of Nuance OmniForm, or a software for editing .ofm files?

Answer (score 2):

Nuance OmniForm has been discontinued by Nuance in 2005 and is no longer sold or supported: I agree with Nico Schuele it seems like nobody had reverse-engineered the format and since it got ended a decade ago I'm not very optimistic that anyone will do it. That said, .ofm files can be [opened](http://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/ofm) and edited by [Nuance OmniPage](http://www.nuance.co.uk/for-business/by-product/omnipage/standard/index.htm) (might need the ultimate edition), which has a [free trial](http://www.nuance.co.uk/for-business/by-product/omnipage/professional/trial-version/index.htm), and maybe they can allow export to more friendly formats.

Answer (score -2):

There are none. `.ofm` looks like a proprietary file type and thus, no editors can provide this functionality.

Comment: Just because it is a proprietary file format does not mean no editors *can* provide that functionality. If no one with the ability to create something has needed that then it does probably mean there isn't anything. For example `.esp` is the proprietary plugin format that Bethesda uses for The Elderscrolls (III, IV and V) as well as Fallout NV  & Fallout 3 and yet there are quite a few third party editors for them (including some that I've contributed significantly to).